# TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'arr' and 'n'

Tags: python, class, typeerror

This is a problem of the missing number in python.

```
class Missing:

    n = int(input())
    arr = list(map(int,input().split(" "))) 

    def __init__(self,arr,n):
        self.arr = arr
        self.n = n
    
    def MissingNumber(self):
        self.res = self.n*(self.n+1)/2
        self.sum_array = sum(self.arr)
        return "Missing no. is ",self.res-self.sum_array

Obj = Missing()
Obj.MissingNumber()
```

I am getting this error.
can anybody solve it?

```
Obj = Missing()
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'arr' 
and 'n'
```

Comment: `Obj = Missing(n,arr) `

Comment: You have to supply the two arguments `arr` and `n` that you specified in `def __init__`. And you shouldn't have tried to initialise them inside your class definition.

Comment: Not working,
'NameError: name 'n' is not defined'

Comment: @leaf_yakitori
can you pls write this entire code once again and paste it here?

Comment: @Ajay Kathwate already add whole code in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need put the input outside class,and assign it when you create instance by `Obj = Missing(arr,n)`

code:

```
class Missing:
    def __init__(self,arr,n):
        self.arr = arr
        self.n = n
        
    def MissingNumber(self):
        self.res = self.n*(self.n+1)/2
        self.sum_array = sum(self.arr)
        return "Missing no. is ",self.res-self.sum_array
        
n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int,input().split(" "))) 
Obj = Missing(arr,n) 
print(Obj.MissingNumber())
```

result:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
('Missing no. is ', 0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

your constructor need two parameter. You need to assign it before it run.

you need to assign n and arr   outside class object

```
class Missing:
    def __init__(self,arr,n):
        self.arr = arr
        self.n = n
    
    def MissingNumber(self):
        self.res = self.n*(self.n+1)/2
        self.sum_array = sum(self.arr)
        return "Missing no. is ",self.res-self.sum_array

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = list(map(int,input().split(" "))) 
    Obj = Missing(n,arr)
    Obj.MissingNumber()
```